Needs help running a Hardhat-based smart contract and it's test script on Hyperledger Besu

First, I am using the binary distribution of Hyperledger Besu on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Second, I do not want to use the quorum quickstart for Besu. The reason being, I need a minimum of 20 accounts with 10K+ eth (possibly) for running a stress testing script. I have already created public-private key pairs using this script, and I would like to use them for testing :-
accounts.js

const ethers = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs');

const numAccounts = 20;
const accounts = [];

// Generate 20 accounts
for (let i = 0; i < numAccounts; i++) {
  const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
  accounts.push({
    privateKey: wallet.privateKey,
    publicKey: wallet.address,
  });
}

// Write accounts to a file
fs.writeFileSync(
  'accounts.json',
  JSON.stringify(accounts, null, 2),
  'utf-8'
);


Third, the stress testing script has 200+ transactions. Is there any way to simulate that test on Besu, once the smart contract has been deployed? The purpose is to measure how many transactions it can mine in a second/minute.
Finally, about my Hyperledger Besu network. I am running 5 nodes with QBFT consensus. Here is my genesis.json

{
  "config" : {
    "chainId" : 1337,
    "berlinBlock" : 0,
    "qbft" : {
      "blockperiodseconds" : 2,
      "epochlength" : 30000,
      "requesttimeoutseconds" : 4
    }
  },
  "nonce" : "0x0",
  "timestamp" : "0x58ee40ba",
  "gasLimit" : "0x47b760",
  "difficulty" : "0x1",
  "mixHash" : "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
  "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc" : {
    "DC790DaA2c5806d7694f30c6522111fCc3d16EB1" : {
      "privateKey" : "f09500f190923957928fd47279fe34d996e27db58c89a86b33ddcc8c98d950a7",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0DDa4A450a10092c318330Ad32e4b38aF35e5c2A" : {
      "privateKey" : "a4bc3414631c63f00cdecd4b631d2611ea57d2f9baa53a7fc8cb28b2ecd0d21c",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "a805C16daa121fAEfb287B1FF6620f56557af0Aa" : {
      "privateKey" : "0b241856a2411affc916847c1e1fd0fdd81581569222e0d5f13ba1f259d6abf7",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "dE5345F972c32f8b35408b33614A427D08044344" : {
      "privateKey" : "1cc2bb862c444bbf3c25733d0fe379817ae4c2c9d7738f9c8dee14280d7fcc73",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "f9E76ab84293dEA2296649b374D62C7aA30064Da" : {
      "privateKey" : "2f8227a137ddc3c240578a87d9d13c005987feecc532e31c073edc3dc51d22ac",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "97bf0d36f7D24aF88a6158188Ae66D1B1388EE97" : {
      "privateKey" : "a95696a4fab669abecfcbbc43f7b0a585e0c161aa7ab1b792f58815d14e22b01",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "85b8916a0D1c19660E2A48137Ec16dC30F0858d5" : {
      "privateKey" : "b2f2674c57699f215c6e26dc5595c1baeb0a3a691c8ad00b64ebc5ca4713fce9",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "622250Ca1A5c866d4a9b846c5e7caa672EF3D9B5" : {
      "privateKey" : "c466e076dc7d5ca12ba84cf4ce92ac76685f147c2a1eef45da4eb9de98d24e1f",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "b83d3AF75cb191FE5DCA03aD78BF48b82D7B8122" : {
      "privateKey" : "c6dc62bc98fbf05e6dad10c88d2c9f89398f31b371c43760eb98e8f719aeaf8d",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "cEE14373704d5AAfebEf60577eD04971262c6c3B" : {
      "privateKey" : "539856dd368ed96610c13095d0b152bf0e91c3c83381425418427468a25e58d",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "CAEc1CFC0571D29Ff6eaaB028D11D1FFC6462F78" : {
      "privateKey" : "e65d08f297a8fdec88d9bc3b0869ae29b9ff8dac44f407bb74caf9bf4d8ff3b2",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "9e2944110406390fCf3Ec7E798F30A7FC010c442" : {
      "privateKey" : "836779e53c83cfcfab54bf92412918a5ab0284270474391f1fb9d9fd4ae178bd",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "Bc425De50108374d673E49f12357D4d88f2b2b3b" : {
      "privateKey" : "f6d304e139c6c892dfc30256dfa84711875772a40478c75d9d47eeb621044ff7",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "D0DD453a6601163E8a4142913175ea3e88D2b852" : {
      "privateKey" : "802c15519445de8ef4e5aa80b5c0720cb56dd9cfc2eb300097efe8a630a732a6",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "DF38B444c75F77D59b6D3FFA0D91fee7a61845ed" : {
      "privateKey" : "3e862cc44ba87a96401027b862e41bd86b234ba797ec48d1f631926b93da9a35",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "e19b6554fDAb829CE28217D5C373147FE2B36863" : {
      "privateKey" : "362f17ffbd7e3574bf2ab05812bd6e278959933af370a121c1b7cf62dfda30ee",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "1592e455c37cF2B242395B24Faabbe6370B149D4" : {
      "privateKey" : "7551ca5860abb12b9b8b397e1ce4dc599bef4d9f1e65cd3a0244ac5f3cf0600f",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "6AD1d91821DB18CCE160aec27379c8aCa41fd954" : {
      "privateKey" : "60acb2f3091dfcb025ae27ade73696ffcaa0375e9e565b0777725ce11ab9c558",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    },
    "53781dEaEc3f646D7AA82DeFB56e95Dbb072B83E" : {
      "privateKey" : "83d3ea6256f55616629ae8ff6336d04cb99bec1a1e96b500884f9b4979e8002d",
      "comment" : "private key and this comment are ignored.  In a real chain, the private key should NOT be stored",
      "balance" : "90000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "extraData" : "0xf88fa00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f869948e4b1ad90620677af6bc7b49d62524378a87dae794ebc806e45948d552f34cd1c6b172caf3cfad832294c0946268f4f0400ba59d9a3c30421eaba0b5f31894dc1fbad697515f0e262f95fc0c85cedcdbacbe529464a8015c5a459961dfdec9318e25a6de7e405abec080c0"
}

I want any help possible for running my massive script of 200+ transactions on the Dapp while deployed on Hyperledger Besu.
Please help me, as I have been stuck here for 2 weeks.
